# Inputting Data from an Excel CSV File into R

Tags: r, excel, input

I am brand new to the R system and I am struggling with it.

I have tried to import data from an Excel CSV file into R.

A tutorial showed me that the data should then be viewable in the "Environment" tab but this is not the case for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the link to the tutorial and more info on how you do it, any message from console?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different packages to import `.csv` into R. A common method is this

```
df <- read.csv("Path/where/your/CSV/file/is/located/on/your/computer/File Name.csv")
```

You need to let R know where your file is located on your computer. This is known as a path. So for example, if I had a file saved in my downloads I would use the following path (I am using a Mac)

```
df <- read.csv("/Users/username/Downloads/File Name.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @the_one_neuron's answer:
I had great expirience with the `readr` package. You can influence a lot of parameters like the delimiter for instance. If it is a very large `csv` file the `vroom` package might be the right joice.